# How to use spcific HERE country data offline?

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Here maps evaluation (90 days) now.
My purpose is to use HERE offline (i.e., with Android phones that do not have cellular data, and even do not have WiFi, but can only make and get calls) and I want the map data to be avaailable only in 1 country.
How can I do this with HERE api?
EDIT
What I did so far:
1. I downloaded the evaluation of HERE, and built simple app. This app is only working with WiFi/Cellular data.
2. I downloaded HERE apk from Google Play and there it gave me to navigate offline after I downloaded the country map from the application.
I want this offline feature in an application that I write.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far

Comment: Now you can see what I tried under EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Be sure that you are using **Premium** version of SDK. **Starter** version didn't support offline mode. Difference between versions shown on this page https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks
2) Look at example for how to download a map for specific region https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/MapDownloader.zip

Comment: The example contains the id of Berlin/Brandenburg. What is the id of Israel?

Comment: You need to use method getMapPackages() and in the callback, you will receive a list of all available maps with ID and other details. Look at https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-odml-maploader.html#topic-apiref__getmappackages-void