# onGetMapPackagesComplete resultCode returns NO_Connectivity

Tags: android, here-api

I want to download a Map for Offline usage but the `onGetMapPackagesComplete` always receives `NO_CONNECTIVITY` as  resultCode and the rootMapPackage is `null`. I added the externalmapLoader-functionality from here [How to use spcific HERE country data offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248438/how-to-use-spcific-here-country-data-offline) to my App. I got Wifi and mobile data turned on. Is there anything else i need to configure to get the Offline functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the MapEngine to offline mode?

The MapLoader requires the MapEngine to be in online mode.